# What is the meaning of 拿 in 他就拿我没办法的信念?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have encountered the following sentence:
他就拿我没办法的信念
in the following paragraph:

> 抱着誓死不从，他就拿我没办法的信念，我只有拼命挣扎，但是我错了。

which was originally [here](http://health.sohu.com/20041120/n223089261.shtml) (link now broken).

I couldn't understand the meaning of 拿 here. Any definition from the dictionary doesn't make sense to me.

As for the 信念， I think it refers to the 信念 in a previous paragraph in the text:

> 在我的印像中，但凡强奸如果女的不愿意，誓死不从的话，男的很少能得逞的，所以我当时就是抱了这样的信念的

The best translation that I could come up with is:

> He could not do anything with my belief

Or in other words, he couldn't make me stop fighting.  But I feel pretty uncomfortable with this translation. It doesn't seem correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding punctuation might help.

抱着“誓死不从，他就拿我没办法”的信念，我只有拼命挣扎，但是我错了。

拿...没办法, literally 'take ... with no solution', is an idiomatic way to say 'could do nothing about ...'.

誓死不从，他就拿我没办法 = (If I am) determined to resist to the end of my life, he could do nothing (to make me yield).

抱着...的信念 = with the idea/belief/conviction that ...

So the whole sentence goes

> With the idea that he couldn't do anything as long as I am determined to resist, I struggled hard with every string pulled, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right. It sounds weird even in Chinese. So I'd say it's the problem with the original sentence, not your translation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know other similar sayings (slang, probably) like 把...搞定(be able to solve/resolve)，把...拿下 (get it done)，then the meaning of 拿...没办法 is have no control of someone or certain situation. Reasons could be different though, lack of power, ability, or simply don't have time or not wanting to deal with.